# Ajax load: callback called but content not loaded into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have defined the following two functions in an external javascript file:

```
function show_sidebar_left(url, sb_width, sb_time){
    $('#sidebar_left').css({'left':-sb_width, 'width': sb_width}); 
    $('#sidebar_left').animate({"left":"0px"}, sb_time, function(){
        $('#sidebar_left').load(url, function(){
            alert("test");
        });
        $('#sidebar_left').addClass('sidebar_left_open');
    });
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(200);
}

function hide_sidebar_left(speed){

    var sidebar_left_pos = parseInt($('#sidebar_left').css('width'),10) + 20;
    $('#sidebar_left').html('');
    if($('#sidebar_left').hasClass('sidebar_left_open')){
        $('#sidebar_left').animate({"left":'-' + sidebar_left_pos + 'px'}, speed, function(){
            $('#sidebar_left').removeClass();
        });
        $('#overlay').fadeOut(200);                
    }

}
```

It is a sliding div that I want to populate with the content of an external php file (just containing some html tags). 
I call the file with:

```
    $('#bars_tb_search').click(function(){
        show_sidebar_left('http://www.zwoop.be/develop/home/bars/bars_toolbox/toolbox_search.php', 550, 300); 
        });
```

The div slides correctly as intended so that works.
The "alert" in the callback function of the Ajax load is properly called.
But... my div is not loaded (which I checked in the elements inspector in Google Chrome).

The console doesn't indicate a Javascript error regarding this load.
Any ideas what my problem might be or what I may be doing wrong?

**Edit**
In the picture, it shows you the css styles applied.

[image: Inspector]

When I resize the page, this happens now: 
[image: Resize]

Does that make any sense to you? I'm losing faith :-s

**Edit2**

The page that is loaded does not contain extra css, it is a php page with static html:

```
<p style="text-align: center">
    <i>
        Note that these filters are applied on top of the results, already filtered by the search categories and tags.
    </i>
</p>
<p style="text-align: center">
    <i>
        To filter on <b>all</b> bars, you can remove the previous filters here: 
    </i>
</p>
```

Comment: Is the calling script also on `www.zwoop.be`?

Comment: Possibly a SOP issue (Same Origin Policy). Is the loaded content on the same domain and subdomain and are you using the same protocol (http) as for your current page?

Comment: @Archer: Yes, it is in the same domain.

Comment: @devnull: I just tested the complete link now and if I visit this link, it is displayed in my web browser...

Comment: Does the class `.sidebar_left_open` have some CSS implications that might render the content invisible?

Comment: @Kim Gysen this was not the question. The question is: Are your current page (the one that holds the above code) and the loaded content on the same domain `http://www.zwoop.be`?

Comment: @Devnull69 Yes both content and current page are in the same domain (http://www.zwoop.be/develop -> but with a different path). Its content cannot be invisible, I just double checked but I didn't make such a declaration. As a matter of fact, I just tested it again, and it works again now when I reloaded the page. Do you see something wrong with my code overall?

Comment: Edit: it doesn't work again, so I'm still looking for a solution...

Comment: Why are you adding `$('#sidebar_left').addClass('sidebar_left_open');
` before *and* after the load() call? Also are you trying to animate that div open while it is loading?

Comment: That's a mistake, thanks for spotting. I'll delete the last line. Anyhow, I didn't make any definitions for this class yet, it doesn't do anything at this point.

Comment: Are you getting a response back?If you are and the content is not being displayed, its got to be something CSS related issue.

Comment: @manraj82 The callback function works. What is weird about the content is that it pops up when I resize the browser window. I haven't implemented a resize function either. I created two buttons that do exactly the same thing, but reference to another zwoop php (both in the same directory). One seems to work now, the other shows this strange behaviour. Both are merely php files with static html. I'm worried because it seems to act unpredictably; I don't see what's wrong with my code though...